# How do I create a TCP listening socket in Rust

Tags: sockets, rust, tcp, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I am using TcpListener from the standard library

I have a public function that is supposed to start up a listening socket

```
pub fn start_listen(){
    let mut file = File::open("Listen.toml").unwrap();
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();
    let value = contents.parse::<Value>().unwrap();

    let ip = value["ip"].as_str().unwrap().to_string();
    let port = value["port"].as_str().unwrap().to_string();
    let socket_string = format!("{}:{}", &ip, &port);
    println!("socket_string -> {}", &socket_string);

    TcpListener::bind(&socket_string).unwrap();
    println!("now listening!");
}
```

and I call it from main.rs

```
    start_listen::start_listen();
    println!("waiting 30s...");
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(30));
    println!("closing program!");
```

The problem is the function runs for the 30 seconds and breaks without any errors, but I cannot see the listening socket when I look for it. I am on Ubuntu.

I have tried manually typing in ip and ports like "127.0.0.1:8080" but the program runs just fine without me being able to find that socket.

Does anyone know what issue I am having? Thanks!

EDIT:

The commands I am using to try and see if the listening socket exists

`sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`

I do not see anything that indicates that socket exists

EDIT2:

Adding this did nothing

```
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        println!("Connection established!");
    }
```

Comment: @prog-fh I'm coming from Python

Comment: Have you read the [Final Chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html) of The Book yet?  That example literally starts with a single-threaded web server, so gives the basics of TCP in Rust.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I am using the exact same line of code as other guides on the internet suggest to open a socket. The only thing missing out is the ability to accept data. All I want to do for now is see if the socket exists, baby steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`TcpListener::bind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.bind) creates a new `TcpListener` and returns it. The socket is closed when this `TcpListener` is dropped.

Modify your `start_listen()` function like this to save the `TcpListener` and return it:

```rust
pub fn start_listen() -> TcpListener {
    ...
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&socket_string).unwrap();
    println!("now listening!");
    listener
}
```

Then in the `main.rs` save the listener before you wait for 30 seconds:

```rust
let listener = start_listen::start_listen();
println!("waiting 30s...");
sleep(Duration::from_secs(30));
println!("closing program!");
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the socket gets deleted when the start_listen public function gets out of scope. Adding a timer to that function confirmed this, guess I need to figure out how to make sure it doesn't go out of scope

Comment: functions do not go out of scope, when your main functions returns, it will end the whole process and with that also all the TCP handlers.